# Python going onto the next line in a file when it shouldn't be

Tags: python, file, notepad

Alright, so I am still relatively new to Python programming, and this seems pretty simple, but I must just be missing something really simple. So, I am trying to make a really simple text editor based addition/subtraction/multiplication/division solver, and everything was going great, and everything works okay, except for how it actually writes the answer to the file. I want it to write it on the same line, but it goes down to the next line for some reason.

```
stopwords = ['\n']
array = fileIWant.readlines()
array = [array for array in array if array not in stopwords]
fileIWant.close()
editFile = open('C:/Users/JustA/Desktop/Python Shenanigans/Solving Equations/Equations.txt', 'w')
array_length = len(array)

for i in range(array_length):
    data = array[i].split()
    if data[1] == '+':
        answer = str(int(data[0]) + int(data[2]))
        editFile.write(str(array[i]) + ' ' + answer)
    if data[1] == '-':
        answer = str(int(data[0]) - int(data[2]))
        editFile.write(str(array[i]) + ' ' + answer)
    if data[1] == '*':
        answer = str(int(data[0]) * int(data[2]))
        editFile.write(str(array[i]) + ' ' + answer)
    if data[1] == '/':
        answer = str(int(data[0]) / int(data[2]))
        editFile.write(str(array[i]) + ' ' + answer)

    editFile.write("\n")
print(array)
editFile.close()
```

That is what the code looks like. The way I see what I am doing is that once it has already solved the equation it goes to the next line for the next one, but for some reason the answer goes to the next line as well. If somebody could help me that would be much appreciated! This is what the notepad looks like:
[image: This is what the notepad looks like: (Not how I want it)]

This is what I want it to look like:[[image: This is what I want it to look like: (How I want it)[2]]

Comment: I think all your subsequent `if`s should be `elif`s instead. Also, when dealing with files use [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)! Oh, and your `for i in range(array_length)` is just begging to be `for element in array`.

Comment: One more thing: [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), amongst other things, could really simplify all the `write()` calls. I’ll write and share an entirely refactored version tomorrow :) To that end, it would be helpful if you could share the entire program.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! Everything is running smoothly now, and I am now going to move onto a different project. It was very satisfying and fun to show people this (it kinda blew their minds even though it was a simple thing), even though you people had some very good suggestions that I need to fix before moving on. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Good luck in your future endeavours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is the `\n`

you can solve it easily to filter out the `\n`, like this:

```
array = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in array if line not in stopwords]
```

Comment: _`for array in array`_ Will that even run?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile checked it and it worked, i agree it's confusing

Comment: @CoolMan You should probably change that `for array in array thing`.

Comment: How about `strip()`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Agreed, it might be a better choice. Although now I’m confused as to what OP is trying to do.